# How to save dbTreelist as XML-File

Tags: xml, delphi, recursion

I have a dbTreelist as below:

[image: structure of dbTreelist]

It's no problem to iterate, but that doesn't help if I want to save it as an XML file (using IXMLNODE etc). I think the best way to accomplish the goal is recursion, but I fail miserably. I get all the nodes, but each node is part of its predecessor, so there is no tree structure. Does anyone have an idea for me? Many thanks in advance.

I tried by recursion but didn't succeed (no tree-structure in the resulting XML-file)

Comment: Nobody codes by text alone. If you provide no code of what you attempted so far and which is compilable to every reader to reconstruct your problem, you can't expect an answer with code either. Or interest.

Comment: Recursion sounds just right. Your approach seems like the right one. There must be some simple mistake with the way you coded it. If you show your code, then it might be possible to point out what the error is.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable to add the solution into the question itself. If you've found that solution and want to share it, do so by posting an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. For more information, see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your comments! @AmigoJack: You are absolutely right, no code = no answer/interest. Sorry! After a lot of try and error I tried by recursion but didn't succeed (no tree-structure in the resulting XML-file)found that solution:

```
    procedure TForm1.AddChildNodes(ParentNode: TcxTreeListNode; 
    XMLParentNode: IXMLNode);
    var
      ChildNode: TcxTreeListNode;
      XMLChildNode:  IXMLNode;
      I: Integer;
    begin
      for I := 0 to ParentNode.Count - 1 do
      begin
        ChildNode := ParentNode.Items[I];
        XMLChildNode := XMLParentNode.AddChild(ChildNode.Texts[0]);
        AddChildNodes(ChildNode, XMLChildNode);
      end;
    end;
    
    procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      XMLDoc: IXMLDocument;
    begin
      XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
      XMLDoc.Active :=  true;
      XMLDoc.DocumentElement := XMLDoc.CreateElement('Treelist', '');
    
      AddChildNodes(cxTreeList1.Root, XMLDoc.DocumentElement);
    
      XMLDoc.SaveToFile('Test.xml');
      ShowMessage('Test.xml saved!');
    end;
```